# Issue with PHP Function - Setting Cookie Value

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

I had the below piece of code for a few months and it got to function very well, but out of nothing it failed to work with no reasons. I have inspected the code several times but with no luck to find what went wrong.

Could you please help me to find out what went wrong.

This is a screen shot from the cookies window in Chrome

[Screen shot from Cookies Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2r1K.png)

The issue is that the below cookies have zero values.

```
setcookie("bookinginfo[cart_discount]", $cart_discount, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) , "/", ".tourexperts-eg.com", true, true);

setcookie("bookinginfo[cart_price]", $cart_price, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) , "/", ".tourexperts-eg.com", true, true);
```

And this one was not set at all and is missing.

```
setcookie("bookinginfo[tour_price]", $tour_final_price, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) , "/", ".tourexperts-eg.com", true, true);
```

The full function code is as follows.

```
function wpcf7_save_data($wpcf7_data)
{

    if ( $wpcf7_data->id !== 5 )
        return;

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ($submission)
    {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }

    $tour_date = $posted_data['tour-date'];
    $adult_no = $posted_data['no-adult'];
    $child_no = $posted_data['no-child'];
    $url = getenv('HTTP_REFERER');
    $title = get_the_title(url_to_postid($url));
    $id = get_page_by_title($title, OBJECT, 'product');
    $tour_id = $id->ID;
    $tour_price = get_post_meta($tour_id, 'tour_price', true);
    $tour_discount_price = get_post_meta($tour_id, 'tour_discount_price', true);
    if(!empty($tour_discount_price))
    {
        $tour_final_price = $tour_discount_price;
    }
    else
    {
        $tour_final_price = $tour_price;
    }

    if ($adult_no >= 15)
    {
        $adults_price = $adult_no * $tour_final_price * 0.4;
    }
    else
    if ($adult_no >= 7)
    {
        $adults_price = $adult_no * $tour_final_price * 0.6;
    }
    else
    if ($adult_no >= 3)
    {
        $adults_price = $adult_no * $tour_final_price * 0.8;
    }
    else
    {
        $adults_price = $adult_no * $tour_final_price;
    }

    $children_price = $child_no * $tour_final_price * 0.5;

    $total_pax = $adult_no + $child_no;

    $cart_price = number_format(($adults_price + $children_price),0,'',',');

    $cart_discount = ($total_pax * $tour_final_price) - $cart_price;

    setcookie("bookinginfo[tour_date]", $tour_date, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) , "/", ".tourexperts-eg.com", true, true);
    setcookie("bookinginfo[cart_discount]", $cart_discount, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) , "/", ".tourexperts-eg.com", true, true);
    setcookie("bookinginfo[cart_price]", $cart_price, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) , "/", ".tourexperts-eg.com", true, true);
    setcookie("bookinginfo[tour_price]", $tour_final_price, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) , "/", ".tourexperts-eg.com", true, true);
    setcookie("bookinginfo[tour_id]", $tour_id, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) , "/", ".tourexperts-eg.com", true, true);
    setcookie("bookinginfo[adult_no]", $adult_no, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) , "/", ".tourexperts-eg.com", true, true);
    setcookie("bookinginfo[child_no]", $child_no, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) , "/", ".tourexperts-eg.com", true, true);

    $wpcf7_data->skip_mail = true;

    global $woocommerce;

        WC()->cart->empty_cart( true );
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart($tour_id,$total_pax);
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_add_discount_line' );
```

Comment: Your code is setting 7 different cookies. Only those 3 you mentioned at the beginning of your post are missing? Or all of them?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó i have edited my question to illustrate your point. Thanks for taking time to look at my question.

Comment: Just to make sure, is the date&time correctly set on your server?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó if the time & date are wrongly set on my server then all cookies wouldn't have been set at all, am i right?

Comment: Correct, never mind :) This came in mind before you've edited your post...

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the request with some sort of (in-browser) developer tools, to see if the cookie headers are correctly sent to the browser?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó i have checked the application cookies to see the cookies values and unfortunately that all are set correctly. I guess that some wordpress codes have been changed with the recent updates? But yet i can not find what went wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "checked the application cookies"...

Comment: In Chrome under developer tools you can find Application tab where you will find cookies data

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include a screenshot with that tab where the cookies & their values to be set are visible?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó I attached a screen shot from the cookies window for more illustration

Comment: Please check on the "Network" tab of the developer tools. (You have to click the URL that is setting the cookies and see the request headers in the "Headers" tab - you will see the exact cookie headers your code is sending to the browser).